# What should be done with questions marked as [Resolved]?

Tags: discussion, questions

For example:

These two questions the OP marked as [Resolved] and left no explanation of how:

1. [[Resolved]Zend Framework: Add form in layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11892715/561731)
2. [[Resolved]Zend Framework: Ajax post data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12167461/561731)

What should be done with them?

They are still legit questions, but with no apparent solution.

Comment: First of all edit the title (already taken care of)...

Comment: We also don't really need tags in titles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not much.

- Edit the title to remove the `[Resolved]` mention, of course
- You may also leave a comment to the author to suggest he uses the tick to mark the correct answer instead of editing the title, if his problem is solved. If he fixed his problem himself, you can suggest he writes an answer, and accepts it.
- If you are able to evaluate the answers yourself, vote to move the correct answers on top of the list.

But ultimately, the fact of accepting an answer belongs to the author, and to him only.

Comment: *I was here first, grmbl*

Comment: Such is life on the Stack Exchange. :-P

Comment: I'd word the second hint very carefully.  It should be something along the lines of "please, instead of editing the title to indicate that a question is answered, accept an answer", so people don't misinterpret it as "improve your accept rate" or "you should accept an answer".

Comment: @casperOne - ah, indeed, forgot about that. We really need to get [rid of such rate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate)

Answer (score 9):

First thing to do is comb the comments/edits by the asker; note in the second one they edited in:

> I fix this problem when I remove: "dataType: 'json'". Thanks for all replies :).

In this case I'd ask them to post that as an answer (if they show recent activity and you reasonably believe they might actually do it) or write up their solution (assuming it works) as a Community Wiki answer if the asker doesn't respond to placing the answer in an answer, or  if you really really doubt they'll do it themselves; those year old unregistered users aren't coming back.

Failing that, post a comment asking "sounds like you solved this one; could you post the solution as an answer?"

Finally, edit "resolved" out of the title after you've done one of the above; if there's an answer that solves the problem, there's no need for the Resolved title. If there isn't, the Resolved title is unneeded *and* incorrect. Just don't edit it out without posting the real answer or leaving a comment saying "hey, sounds like you solved this, what worked?" otherwise it's not readily apparent they (somehow) solved it.

Answer (score 6):

You remove the `[Resolved]` part of the title and leave a comment explaining how to accept answers instead.

I've edited the titles already, and [left such a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167461/zend-framework-ajax-post-data#comment16364493_12167461).

If the OP resolved the issue themselves, encourage them to post their solution as a new answer. You can even do this yourself if they put the answer in the question post, and don't respond to the comments. Make it a CW post to avoid accusations of trying to harvest reputation with other peoples work though.

Answer (score 4):

<s>Remove the mark</s>. Somebody did it already. :P

If it happens again, I'd suggest leaving a comment explaining that here we don't use the same methods that forums use.

On a forum board you cannot know if a thread reached a solution or not, here you can, thanks to the fact that questions with an accepted answer get a green square.